# Form is not submitting inside function jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sql, asp-classic, ado

I have some jquery code that executes the function doneTyping when the user finishes typing, this works with any code. But when I try to submit the form using "$('#searchf').submit();" the form doesn't submit. I've tried quite a few variations.

Does anyone know why it isn't working? - Jquery code below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cat").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})

var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#legal').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#legal').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    $('#searchf').submit();
     alert("Your book is overdue.");
}

});
</script>
```

PAGE CODE

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
pagetitle="Contractor Details"
%>
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/header.htm"-->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/menu.htm"-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cat").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})

var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#legal').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#legal').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    $('#searchf').submit();
     alert("Your book is overdue.");
}

});
</script>
<div class="twoColumnRow">
<div class="twoColumnContent">
<p class="breadCrm"><a href="/index.htm">Home</a> <span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/index.htm">Tools of the Trade</a> <span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/finance/index.htm">Finance and Purchasing</a><span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/finance/procurement/index.htm">Procurement and Contracts information</a></p>
<div class="contentPad">
<!-- Start of main content -->

<p class="imageRight">&nbsp;</p>
<h1><%=pagetitle%></h1>

<%
        Dim connectString, connect, conDB, sconDB, lDB, con, scon, lcon, src_abn, src_cat
        connectString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data")
              src_legal = Request.QueryString("legal")
              src_cat = Request.QueryString("cat")
        set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        connect.open connectString

        if src_cat = "all" then
        conDB = "SELECT * FROM cont.csv WHERE ucase(legal) LIKE ucase('%"+src_legal+"%')"   
        lDB = "SELECT * FROM cont.csv WHERE ucase(legal) LIKE ucase('%"+src_legal+"%')" 
        else 
        conDB = " SELECT * FROM cont.csv WHERE " & src_cat & " = 'Yes' AND ucase(legal) LIKE ucase('%"+src_legal+"%')"
        lDB = " SELECT * FROM cont.csv WHERE " & src_cat & " = 'Yes' AND ucase(legal) LIKE ucase('%"+src_legal+"%')"
        end if

        sconDB = "SELECT * FROM cont.csv"   

        set con = connect.execute(conDB)
        set scon = connect.execute(sconDB)
        set lcon = connect.execute(lDB)
%>
<h2>Search results</h2>
<% if not con.BOF then %>
<div style="margin-top:1em">

  <form i="searchf" action="dbinstant.htm" method="get">

      <p>Company name:1<br/>
      <input id="legal" name="legal" type="text" value="<%=src_legal%>">
      </p>
     <p>Categories for Creative Design:<br/>
      <select id="cat" name="cat">
        <option class="group" label="All categories" value="all" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "all" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Strategic brand, marketing and communications advice" value="a" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "a" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Graphic design and layout" value="b" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "b" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Forms design" value="c" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "c" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Web design and development" value="d" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "d" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Authoring services" value="e" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "e" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Editorial services" value="f" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "f" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Translation services" value="g" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "g" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Photography and film services" value="h" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "h" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Scanning and digitisation services" value="i" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "i" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Multimedia editing services" value="j" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "j" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <br />

    <table style="font-size:.9em;" class="contentTable">
          <tr>
                <th>ABN:</th>
                <th>Company Name:</td>
          </tr>
  <% con.Movefirst() %>
  <% while (NOT con.EOF) %>
          <tr>
                <td width="120px"><%=con("abn")%></th>
                <td><a href="dbcomp.htm?abn=<%=con("abn")%>&cat=all"><%=con("legal")%></a></td>
          </tr>
  <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
  %>
</table>

</div>
<% else %>
    <% scon.Movefirst() %>
  <form action="dbinstant.htm" method="get">

      <p>Company name:2<br/>
      <input id="legal" name="legal" type="text">
      </p>

     <p>Categories for Creative Design:<br/>
      <select id="cat" name="cat">
        <option class="group" label="All categories" value="all" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "all" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Strategic brand, marketing and communications advice" value="a" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "a" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Graphic design and layout" value="b" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "b" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Forms design" value="c" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "c" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Web design and development" value="d" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "d" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Authoring services" value="e" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "e" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Editorial services" value="f" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "f" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Translation services" value="g" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "g" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Photography and film services" value="h" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "h" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Scanning and digitisation services" value="i" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "i" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Multimedia editing services" value="j" <%if request.querystring("cat") = "j" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <br /><hr />
<p>No records match your query.</p>
<p><a href="dbtest.htm">Return to search page</a></p>
<%
  end if
  con.close
%>


<!-- End of main content -->
</div> <!-- end contentPad div -->
</div> <!-- end twocolumncontent div -->
<div class="twoColumnLinks">

<!--<div class="relatedLinks">
<h3>Related Links</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="/index.htm">Related link 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>--> <!-- end relatedlinks div -->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/quicklinks.htm"-->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/mylinks.htm"-->
</div> <!-- end twocolumnlinks div -->
</div> <!-- end twocolumnrow div -->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/footer.htm"-->
```

Comment: `<form i="searchf"`... Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.form` will always be `undefined` in your context as you never set it up.

```
this.form
  ↑   ↑
  |   └── 'form' is seen as a property of the 'window' object
  └── this is the 'window' object
```

what you would probably want to "say" was

```
$("#cat").change(function () {
    $(this).form.submit();
});
```

but even that would result in a `not a property` exception as `form` is not a property or object of `$("#cat")`...

so, to make things easier for you, instead of `this.form.submit();` change it to either:

```
$("form").submit();
```

or be specific (for when you'll have more than one form in the page)

```
<form id="form1" ... >

$("#form1").submit();
```

even if you don't have more than one `<form>` in the page, it's always a good practice to use the second method!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have mistyped a id of the form tag.

In your code:

```
<form i="searchf" action="dbinstant.htm" method="get">
```

Correct:

```
<form id="searchf" action="dbinstant.htm" method="get">
```

Comment: *-1* this alone does not fix the problem! **first** of all `id` is not required, and `i` is a valid attribute, as we can write whatever we want... browsers will just ignore it (same principle of the `data-` attribute); **second** even after you have changed `i` to `id`, the form will still not be submitted for the reason I expose in my answer.

Comment: Though all id is not required, but if id named "searchf" isn't added to the form, $('#searchf').submit() in doneTyping function is not working.